# ant -f </path/to/build> build-service causes many differences with git repo

Tags: ant, liferay

I noticed that there is a difference in generating the liferay services by Mehod 1:
`ant -f liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.0-ce-ga1/portlets/portlet-name/build.xml build-service` 
and by 
Method 2:
`cd "path to portlet"; ant build-service` 
I don't know the exact difference, but git reports a lot of diffs when I do a `git status` after the first method. With second method git is fine. 
The two diiferences I saw were the following: 
1. No liferay copyright text in method 1 
2. Indentation is different

Any reason for this behaviour? This is not a blocker or something for me but certainly it annoys me to change the directory to each portlet to build the services. Or setting jenkins locally is required.

Answer (score 0):

It is very magic behaviour, and I cann't repeat that.

To use build service e.g. jenkins, set the property for sdk-path.

build.xml:

```
<project name="MyJsfTestPortlet-portlet" basedir="." default="deploy">
    <property file="build.${user.name}.properties"/>
    <import file="${project.dir}/portlets/build-common-portlet.xml" />
</porject>
```

build.myjenkins.properties (in the same dir):

```
project.dir=c:/6.1.GA-1/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1-sdk
```

At once you can use this method to move the portlets from sdk-dir.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That was helpful tip about jenkins. But I still wonder about the strange behavior of ant/liferay. I can reproduce it every time unfortunately :)